# Picking top 5 scores from a range

Tags: excel, rank

I run a small golf eclectic with excel. One of the things we have is a points system. I would like to get the 5 highest points scored over the season and have them ranked from 1 (being the highest points scored) to 5.

My knowledge of excel "sums" goes only a wee bit further than add and subtract.

Thanks!

Comment: If you could give me an example of a few rows of data, I can put something together for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change the order that they are presently in you can use the LARGE function. It returns the kth largest value.

Below is a great formula, if you drag it down it will automatically get the second, third and nth largest value from a table of data (in this example the data is between A1 to A10).

```
=LARGE(A1:A10,ROW(A1)-ROW($A$1)+1)
```

You can then match the values with names or corresponding data from the tables using the MATCH and INDEX functions. The example below would fetch the name for each value from the second column.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$B$10,MATCH(cell reference with score or value,$A$1:$B$10,2))
```

Play around with these formulas, they are very convenient for data m

Answer (score 1):

If you have a column containing the scores, you could add a filter (Data->Filter I think) and sort descending.

Though, if you just have rows that are something like [Date][Person][Score] you'll need to go to another sheet and SUM the scores for each person then sort that... Unfortunately my Excel skills aren't up to par to pull a score for each person like that.

Comment: if in rows, pivot the table first. +1

Answer (score 1):

Given a list of numbers in A1 to A10, you can work out their 'Rank' relative to each other by using 'RANK'.

e.g.

```
RANK(A1,A1:A6,0)
```

RANK(cell, list of cells to check against, order)

For order, 0 = descending.

From there you can work out which one is first pragmatically.

Comment: When you say "RANK(cell, list of cells to check against, order)"
What does the cell refer to? The cell where i want the data to go?
I have total points in column AB, the data is from cell AB6 to AB30. I want the top 5 scores to be displayed in cells AB7 to AB11.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Cell refers to the actual cell in your list you want to rank. So if you want to find the rank of A1 in your list of A1:A20, you go RANK(A1,A1:A20,0). Then, you can duplicate this for A2 to A20, and you get your ranks. Then, you can sort the rankings how you wish, like finding the cell in Column B (the column of RANKS) that contains 1, then using that row in Column A as your answer. I haven't fully worked this out in Excel, but I guess you can do the above and make ranking work programatically, as opposed to AutoFilter.

Comment: Thanks again for replying. I understand the rank command now. i dont think it is what i am after, not sure excel can even do it! Of the 26 rows with the scores i them, i almost want to filter out the top 5. So that they are displayed elsewhere on the worksheet!.
Appreciate any comments!

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2007,

Check that your data is continuous, with no blank rows or columns.  Click on your scores and then select **'Data - Filter'**

Using the dropdown that the filter creates at the top of your scores column and select **'Number filters - Top ten'**

A **'Top ten Autofilter'** dialog will be displayed, reduce the show 10 to 5 and then click on OK.

---

For earlier versions of Excel add a RANK formula in a new column.  Be careful as the scores need to be sorted, usually into descending order.  If there are any ties, they will be given the same ranking number and the subsequent rank number will be incremented by the number of ties. (E.g. If there are two scores of 2, ranked as 5.  The next score will be ranked as 7, not 6)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the LARGE Function as described above, make sure you put the same range in the list for each of the LARGE functions. That is, change =LARGE(A1:A10,ROW(A1)-ROW($A$1)+1) to =LARGE(A$1:A$10,ROW(A1)-ROW($A$1)+1) or you will get some strange incorrect results